# Is there a way to "block" video ads in Admob when the user is using 3g?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I mean, when the user is with the 3g connection only show Text and Image ads in an interstitial ad, and when uses WiFi show this type of ads in order to avoid wasting a lot of MB.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdMob will normally do this kind of thing automatically. The SDK and servers are designed to find and serve the exact right ad for each request, and part of that is not jamming a bunch of video through a 3G connection. :)

If you're especially concerned, though, you can create two different ad unit IDs, turn off video ads explicitly for one of them (it's an option in the ad unit setup on the AdMob web site), and then choose which to use at run time.